# Flutter app not running when emulator is present

Tags: android, dart, flutter, emulation

The emulators are there but when I launch the app it doesn't work, please help :)

I have tried everything.

Cal, Flutter newbie.

I have followed the installation guidelines and tried fixes from other stack flow answers i am running windows 8.1 singular user. i have tried from command prompt and in the android terminal

> <***C:\Users\Callum\first_app> Flutter emulators
>
> 2 available emulators:
>
> Pixel_2_API_27 • pixel_2 • Google • Pixel 2 API 27
>
> Pixel_2_API_28 • pixel_2 • Google • Pixel 2 API 28
>
> To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch '.
>
> To create a new emulator, run 'flutter emulators --create [--name xyz]'.
>
> You can find more information on managing emulators at the links below:
>
> https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds
>
> https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager
>
> C:\Users\Callum\first_app> Flutter emulators --launch Pixel_2_API_28
>
> //emulator launches
>
> C:\Users\Callum\first_app> Flutter run
>
> No connected devices.
>
> C:\Users\Callum\first_app>***>

I want the flutter app to run

UPDATE

> C:\Users\Callum\first_app> flutter doctor -v
>
> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600], 
>   locale en-US)
>
> • Flutter version 1.2.1 at C:\src\flutter\flutter
>
> ```
> • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (3 months ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
>
> • Engine revision 3757390fa4
>
> • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)
> ```
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
>
> 28.0.3)
>
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\Callum\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>
> • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native
>
> profiling support)
>
> • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
>
> • Java binary at: C:\src\Andriod studio\jre\bin\java
>
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-
>
> b01)
>
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
>
> • Android Studio at C:\src\Andriod studio
>
> • Flutter plugin version 35.0.1
>
> • Dart plugin version 183.6270
>
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-
>
> b01)
>
> [!] Connected device
>
> ! No devices available
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

but there are emulators available. Could the problem be the environment variables i have set?;

ANDRIOD_HOME- Value: C:\Users\Callum\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Path- Value: C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin;%ANDRIOD_HOME%\tools;%ANDRIOD_HOME%\platform-tools

**Update 2**

### I have installed vscode. the bottom right says no device, i clicked on it and chose a device(the devices I created in andriod studio were here). I got the following error "Failed to launch emulator: Error: Emulator didn't connected within 60 seconds"

**Update 3**

I tried to run ABD.exe from command prompt, i got the following error : "the program cannot start beacuse api-ms-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. try reinstalling the program to fix this problem". I then downloaded the missing dll and put it in the platform-tools folder.

I also installed C++ developer tools from the windows website as that contained the dll that i was looking for.

I now get a 'the application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) click ok to close application.

After all this, if i remove the dll from the platform tools folder, i still get the error "the program cannot start beacuse api-ms-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. try reinstalling the program to fix this problem"

Comment: which editor you are using? if you are using VScode just use f5 and vscode does everything for you.

Comment: Im using andriod studio, trying to get the first code to work, doing my first app( code comes with the flutter framework). used a video tutorial and the notes from the flutter website.

Comment: Ok.. You need to check this out if it helps [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive?tab=androidstudio)

Comment: Thanks i did... but im missing something between the editor and the emulator.. the editors (andriod studio and VScode) both launch emulator and then fail to connect to the same emulator

Comment: Are you able to start emulator without debug? [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator)

Comment: So on VScode i can open the device and the emulator opens but does not connect. I am able to debug on vscode without using emulator.

Comment: ok. can you take screenshot and put the link here.... if emulator runs then its somethign else which  i need to figure out.

Comment: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2849e0e1140943bea240c8a22fa2c3bb20190501174721/e0fa8c) wetransfer

Comment: Were these what you were looking for?

Comment: i recently had the same problem you need to uninstall and install the emulator to a specific location also set androd_home to your path

Comment: you also need to set **%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools** and **%ANDROID_HOME%\tools**

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue, but in my case, the Emulator was already running successfully via Android Studio, so it was enough for me to just do the following steps:

```
1. Run this command > "Flutter emulators"
2. Select the relevant emulator and run > "flutter emulators --launch Pixel_2_API_28"
3. Within your app folder path, run > "flutter run"
```

**After the last command, you would get something like this message:**

Using hardware rendering with device AOSP on IA Emulator. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software rendering".

Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done

Comment: woa, this worked. I just opened the emulator, runned the "flutter run" and worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and click `Launch Emulator`

Comment: The emulator launches but then cant connect to vscode program

Comment: i cant understand