# How to Fix this error "Gradle View is running and not ending"

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, android-emulator

When I click debug/run Button gradle start running but it is not ending means my app not come on android emulator. I had tried everything but nothing had work for me. If you know the solution please tell me.

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938842/flutter-app-not-running-when-emulator-is-present